# Restrict user to click a tag only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing an issue regarding multiple hit on same time on anchor tag. 
i have page abc.html 
it has an anchor tag. when user click on that link it process one request for order. now what problem i am facing if user click that link multiple times then i am getting duplicate orders. 
So i have decided to to restrict anchor tag for one click only . i did some R&D i found a code  but it is disbale link on first click while i want to disable it on second click.
code as follows

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            a.disabled:link, a.disabled:visited { color: grey; }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(#document).ready(function(){
    $("#disabled a").click(function () {
      $(this).fadeTo("fast", .5).removeAttr("href");
    });
  });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://google.com" onclick="this.removeAttribute('href');this.className='disabled'">Link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to think that it is protecting you (user can desactive javascript for instance). You should check that on the server side. A way to do this is to build a token on the server side and pass it as an hidden field. Then when the user submit, you check the token on the server side again. This will prevent CSRF attacks at the same time.

Comment: In another hand, a request modifying the state of the server (creating orders in your case) should not be a link (HTTP GET method). This should be a POST HTTP request. Use a submit button and a form (this will allow you to do what I said previously).

Answer (score 2):

You may use `one`:

```
$("#disabled a").one('click',function () {
    //to do here
});
```

Sample example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#link').one('click', function() {
    console.log('in here ...');
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.w3schools.com" id='link'>W3 Schools</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use (edited code):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var isLinkActive = true;

                $("#link").click(function (event) {
                    if (isLinkActive) {
                        isLinkActive = false;
                    } else {
                        window.location.hash = '';
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#test" id='link'>Link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

However I wouldn't recommend to rely on that to prevent the double use of a link (user can desactive javascript for instance). You should check that on the server side. A way to do this is to build a token on the server side and pass it as an hidden field. Then when the user submit, you check the token on the server side again. This will prevent CSRF attacks at the same time.

In the other hand, a request modifying the state of the server (creating orders in your case) should not be a link (HTTP GET method). This should be a POST HTTP request. Use a submit button and a form (this will allow you to do what I said previously).

Comment: Tell me if there is a problem!

Comment: didn't work bro. let me know you what actually i am trying to do , actually my order image with anchor tag took time to process order during this time if any user click on same image again then it process another order i want to prevent it.. now i have other idea put an alert on click  so user can not click twice on that image . but i need an autotimer after 5 second alert disappear and process link

Comment: Sorry I didn't test it. I corrected it and provided my code. `window.location.hash = '';` is just used to show the wanted behaviour (look at the url).

Comment: my tag looks like - <a id="link" onclick="submitForm();"><img src="order_button_big.png" alt="Order Now" width="200" height="100" border="0" title="Order Now"></a>

Comment: With my new code it should work. I pasted your own and copied the typo `$(#document)` which was throwing an error. Sorry. Note the comment I added on the GET and POST HTTP methods.